# PySFML build not working

Tags: python, build, sfml

I'm trying to get PySFML-1.6 with Python 2.7 following [these](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-python.php) instructions. I direct to the SFML directory and enter

```
python setup.py build -cmingw32
```

and I get this error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find
d -lsfml-graphics
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find
d -lsfml-window
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find
d -lsfml-audio
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find
d -lsfml-system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow it?

> If you want to build PySFML from the source code, you must have the SFML C++ headers and libraries in the SFML-x.x directory (as well as the "python" folder)

Anyway, why not just download pre-compiled files [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php)?

Comment: I have them in both. Which version is the pre-compiled?

Comment: Download link: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sfml/SFML-1.6-python2.7-win32.zip